# Fetch current ADFS credential on the mobile device?

Tags: android, ios, active-directory, token, adfs

I’m new to ADFS. The mobile device is already in domain (authenticated via ADFS already). I’m working on a mobile app and I don’t want the user to input manually user name and password again, just use the the current ADFS credential to fetch the token. Is that possible? And how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IWA is what you are after and that only works on a browser if it is configured. IE is the only browser that does this by default.

On mobile, I suspect you also need to attach the device by DRS or via Intune?